# Registering every Windows login try

Tags: authentication, windows-embedded

I want to keep a log with the attempted log-in to a machine. The OS is Windows Embbeded Standard. Is it possible to make Windows execute an application or a script after every login attempt to enable me to save that information in my database?

**EDIT:**

Extract from [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/37722/registering-every-windows-login-try/37731#37731):

"Here, you can set auditing to all types of events. I believe the one you want is "Audit logon events", Set it to Failure (or Success as well if you want).
All events will now get sent to Event Viewer. ..."

Is it possible to access the Event Viewer info via WMI?

Comment: I think you would find better pointers on superuser.com, however this belongs to SO too. And by the way, i don't know ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security viewpoint, I would assume this would **not** be possible. But it is possible to write your specialized GINA library which would replace the standard login system of Windows. This was done to support fingerprint readers and smart card readers, and many other alternative login methods.

But out of curiosity, what kind of problem are you trying to solve here? Windows already has plenty of build-in functionality which can be analysed by anyone who can log in.

---

Follow [this link](http://www.visualwin.com/Log-in/logging-failed-logins.html) to see how it's done in Windows 2003. I've checked with Windows XP on a virtual machine and it works exactly the same there. So I assume it also works in embedded XP versions.

---

For reading the event log, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8.aspx) from MSDN will be practical too. This will require .NET though, which is optional on Windows XP.

Comment: I have to log any attempt to log in. My best bet was to do it this way, launching an script to keep track of that.

Comment: True, but if it was that easy to run a script during logon then you'd have to fear keyloggers and other nasties. However, I think the event log could be configured to keep track of failed login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

WMI might be a good place to start.  You could use WMI (or another method) to query the security event log for sucessful/failed logon events, too.

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_event_log_administrator.htm